# Purpose of snap and cdrom directories?

Tags: filesystem

I've transitioned from Windows to Linux Ubuntu 18.04 just yesterday and trying to wrap my head around the directory system.

So far it seems very straight-forward, as explained [by Rinzwind in a similar question,](http://askubuntu.com/a/138551/874193) and explained [in the Linux Foundation docs.](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html)

From my root directory, however, I see 2 additional directories listed: `/cdrom` and `/snap`.

What are their specific purposes? Shouldn't `/cdrom` be located under the `/media` directory?  Is the `/snap` directory dedicated to "snap apps"? If so, what makes it different enough to deviate from the `/usr/bin` and `/opt` conventions?

**Note**: Ubuntu is my first Linux distro used, so I do not know if these directories are Ubuntu specific or not.

Comment: About snap, you might want to look at the discussion [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000177/is-the-snap-core-folder-needed).  You might have to look around for a good introductory discussion on snaps; this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snappy_(package_manager)) article might help.  It's basically a new way of managing new software packages that is new (as far as I remember) to 18.04 that co-exists with `apt`.  In short, leave those `/snap` directories alone.  It's not something you need to worry about or even use directly.

Comment: Adherence to the Linux [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) (read it) is not  mandatory. Each distro can do as they see fit.

Comment: @user535733 Adherence isn't mandatory, but minimum of directories from the FSH standard should be followed by an OS claiming itself to be Unix-like. Plus it's a portability consideration for running software on different systems