# Strange new disks appeared in Ubuntu

Tags: filesystem, chromium, bookmarks

All of sudden I noticed two new disks in my Ubuntu 16.04: `/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_5662.snap (deleted)`  and `/var/lib/snapd/snaps/chromium_506.snap (deleted)`  .

**What are they and why did they appear?**

The first disk appeared several days ago. I noticed the second disk only today and shortly after that my Chromium crashed and all bookmarks and browsing history for the last 3 months disappeared. The new disks do not seem to have any Bookmarks files though.

Disks utility does not show any changes to the original actual disks. It looks as if someone has mounted two additional disks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are snap packages. core and chromium are snap packages. You can list installed snap packages using 
 `snap list`. You can read more about snap packages [here](https://docs.snapcraft.io/snap-documentation/3781).

Another more detailed [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1000200/894787)